# Array List Intent extra in Java

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to skip my `ArrayList` through `Intent`. But I cannot find what to write in extra? Any get methods I am getting errors like "not applicable for string."

Item Details:

```
public class ItemDetails {

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getItemDescription() {
    return itemDescription;
}
public void setItemDescription(String itemDescription) {
    this.itemDescription = itemDescription;
}
public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}
public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
}
public int getImageNumber() {
    return imageNumber;
}
public void setImageNumber(int imageNumber) {
    this.imageNumber = imageNumber;
}

public int getVideoNumber() {
    return videoNumber;
}
public void setVideoNumber(int videoNumber) {
    this.videoNumber = videoNumber;
}

public void setChild(ArrayList<ItemDetails> item_child)
{
    this.item_child = item_child;
}
public ArrayList<ItemDetails> getChild()
{
    return this.item_child;
}
public void setParent(ArrayList<ItemDetails> item_parent)
{
    this.item_parent = item_parent;
}
public ArrayList<ItemDetails> getParent()
{
    return this.item_parent;
}



private String name ;
private String itemDescription;
private String price;
private int imageNumber;
private int videoNumber;
private ArrayList<ItemDetails> item_child;
    private ArrayList<ItemDetails> item_parent; 
}
```

My class:

```
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txt_itemName;
    TextView txt_itemDescription;
    TextView txt_itemPrice;
    ImageView itemImage;
    ArrayList<ItemDetails> item_parent;
    ArrayList<ItemDetails> item_child;
}
```

My putExtra:

```
intObj.putExtra("exerciselist",obj_itemDetails.getChild());
```

GetChild function :

```
public ArrayList<ItemDetails> getChild()
{
   return this.item_child;
}
```

But I cannot find how am I supposed to write to get arrayList?

```
ArrayList<ItemDetails> child1 = getIntent().?????????
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> But i cannot find how am ı supposed to write to get arrayList

Short answer: you can't. You can only pass `ArrayList<String>` and then retrieve it with

```
getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("key");
```

**But**. If you want to pass custom objects via Intent your objects have to implement:

- [`Parcelable interface`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) or [`Serializable interface`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html)

You can choose one of them. Both works same but have different implementations.

## Parcelable interface:

If you choose Parcelable interface, your `ItemDetails` class have to implement Parcelable. Then you can put it as

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("key", value);
```

and retrieve it as:

```
getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("key");
```

I won't write you Parcelable implementation because it requires a little more code. Here is [nice example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181526/example-of-implementing-parcelable).

## Serializable interface:

If you choose Serializable interface i suggest you to create class named for instance ItemDetailsWrapper that will wrap your `ArrayList(s)<ItemDetails>`

Both i.e. ItemDetailsWrapper and ItemDetails class have to implement Serializable interface. Now you are able to pass it via Intent like this:

```
getIntent().putExtra("key", <serializableClass>); // storing 
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("key"); // retrieving
```

### Example of implementation:

```
public class ItemDetailsWrapper implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private ArrayList<ItemDetails> itemDetails;

    public ItemDetailsWrapper(ArrayList<ItemDetails> items) {
        this.itemDetails = items;
    }

    public ArrayList<ItemDetails> getItemDetails() {
        return itemDetails;
    }
}

public class ItemDetails implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // getters, setters and properties
}
```

And how to pass through Activities:

```
ItemDetailsWrapper wrapper = new ItemDetailsWrapper(list);
Intent i = new Intent(<context>, <targetActivity>);
i.putExtra("obj", wrapper); // i.putExtra("obj", new ItemDetailsWrapper(list));
// retrieving 
ItemDetailsWrapper wrap = 
                    (ItemDetailsWrapper) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("obj");
ArrayList<ItemDetails> list = wrap.getItemDetails();
```

Comment: Great Answer! The example was spot on!

Comment: Perfect put & get list of array !!!!

Comment: While selecting Parcelable or Serializable keep this in mind that Serializable is slower than Parcelable

Comment: Perfect  explanation :D

Comment: Thank you, the wrapper idea worked for me too! I was getting an HashMap with getSerializableExtra and I was not able to get back my original objects. Using generics you could also create a wrapper that works for many different "ItemDetails"