# How to send List instance to another activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, instance, send

I have class :

```
public class ClassList 
{   
    private String Language1;
    private String Language2;
    public ClassList(String Language1,String Language2)
    {
        this.Language1 = Language1;
        this.Language2 = Language2;
    }
    public String Language1() 
    {
        return this.Language1;
    }
    public String Language2()
    {
        return this.Language2;
    }

}
```

I would like to send ArrayList to another activity by using an instance of this class. Is this possible?

Comment: Your `ClassList` have to implement either `Parcelable` or `Serializable` interface. Have look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15731029/array-list-intent-extra-in-java/15731120#15731120).

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to send ArrayList to another activity by instance using.
>   It is possible?

Assuming you mean, sending the `ClassList` to another `Activity` by using an `Intent`, you 
have to look at the `Parcelable` interface:

[Here's a nice example of how to do it](http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.nl/2010/06/android-parcelable-example.html)